# Redis java map pagination

Tags: redis, redisson

I am thinking of using redis in my java application either through jedis or redisson client. I have a use case where I need to show all the map entries in redis on UI. I can't fetch them all at once because the data is around 100 mb which is a lot over network. How can I fetch the entries in the map by providing a range for pagination?

Comment: Please add more detail. E.g. how are you currently fetching a single entry?

Comment: Depending on your redis data type you can use RANGE commands. For instance ZRANGE command for a sorter list, https://redis.io/commands/zrange. Also SCAN commands gives something similar IMHO like a SQL Cursor, ZSCAN for instance https://redis.io/commands/zscan